# How to use HTTP Sniffer (Chrome Network tab) to auto download files based on file name

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I use the Chrome network tab I there a certain files I can see that have the file have the same names (different address though) each time I go to a different page.

In the network tab I can download the files manually but is there simple way to download the files based on the files name since they are the same per page. I'm sure there is a way to do it with code, but I don't know any code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok There is a number of things you can look at in terms of software that is out there
If you looking for network packets and want to analyse what is moving through your TCP sockets use  [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

If you are looking at copying an entire website to analyse it you can use one of the website grabbers , Ive used Httrack but there is a whole list of them[Website grabbers](https://dynomapper.com/blog/11-content-inventory/287-how-to-download-an-entire-website-for-offline-viewing#:%7E:text=To%20use%20this%20website%20grabber,site%20on%20your%20hard%20disk.)